# JavaScript regular expression to check single special character to occur once in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression like this

```
var regEx = /^([0-9a-z]{7})$|^([0-9a-z-]){8}$/ig;
```

I have to check if the '-'(hyphen) occurs only once in the input string if the string length is 8.

I can check it using javascript, But i want to know if it can be done with regular expressions

Comment: Does the input string contain empty space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the negative lookahead for this:

```
/^[0-9a-z]{7}$|^(?!.*-.*-)[0-9a-z-]{8}$/ig
```

**update**

The regex below allows no hyphen, if length is 7, and it allows one (and no more) hyphen if the length is 8:

```
^[0-9a-z]{7}$|^(?=[^-]*-[^-]*$)[0-9a-z-]{8}$
```

Comment: I think you meant `/^[0-9a-z]{7}$|^(?!.*-.*-)[0-9a-z-]{8}$/ig`

Comment: thanks the solution works, and can it be formed like, the string's length can be 8, only if it contains the hyphen?

Comment: The answer is updated. Is this, what you need @Anthony?

Comment: @Adam That can be considered an approvement for this pattern.